# Happy and Sad Answers Feature

Tags: feature-request, answers, subjective-answers

Well. There are two types of **answers**, IMO, **`Happy`**, and **`Sad`** ones.

When found a "Happy" answer I am happy that a solution of my problem is found.

- *`Happy`* is a real overall solution to the problem.

When any of available answers does not satisfies me, but I understand that this is the "maximum" that is (actually) offered, and I would like to "close" the subject, I accept a 'Sad' answer.

- *`Sad`* is a working workaround, a way to facilitate, but not totally
  resolve the problem. This is when you can't say that you haven't an answer, nor you really have one.

Now if someone in time proposes a new solution to the problem, that will satisfy all of the problem's aspects, I will be able to advance the answer to the Happy 'level'.

By ex, a "Sad" answer could have 5 points, and a "Happy" - 10 points. When passing from Sad to Happy = +5points.

An example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092298/force-exceptions-language-in-english), when I ask for changing the exceptions language to English, there is a `"Sad"` solution (the first one), but this solution does not satisfy me entirely, cause needs some code changes, but I don't want it. Maybe, if one day somebody propose me a solution without the code change, I will have a happy solution, but actually I can't say that I have found the answer, nor I can say that I hadn't found one.

Comment: Why would you think a "no, you can't do this" answer is worthless? IMO, it's much more difficult to prove something is not possible and say it with confidence in a large community like SO than providing a solution.

Comment: @Spammer: Who says that a "This is impossible" could not be a "Happy" answer? I'll mark one argumented like this in my example question above.

Comment: +1 I like the idea happy/sad categories (though I'd leave the rep points alone)

Answer (score 3):

We already have a system for this: voting.

If you're happy with an answer, upvote.
If you're unhappy with an answer, downvote.

If an answer needs work, don't vote, but leave the answerer a comment to encourage them to improve what they said in a way that helps you.

Comment: yes but not every times the answer with the most votes is a accepted answer, from one part, from other, I wouldn't leave a thread without answer if I understand that a best solution can't be found, but the proposed "answer" is not a really answer of the question(finally, does not resolve my problem).

Comment: If I have a "sad" answer, other users know that could propose something new, so perhaps I will change the answer to their other one. If I have a "happy" answer, I am completely satisfied with the solution, so other solutions does not interest me.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Meta-Commentary about the question and its answer is superfluous to the goal of providing an all encompassing resource of programming knowledge.

I hate to sound cold, but people that good don't care about how you feel when you heard the answer, they just care about the solution.

Comment: in the provided concrete example, everybody understand that the really solution is not found, a workaround is found, even if I don't use it, but actually I've hard to believe that a best solution can be proposed.

Comment: But when the _real_ solution is given, it will receive more votes than the workaround answer. It will then (eventually) float to the top and be **the** answer.

Comment: @Michael: But what if a **real** answer is **never** given? Finally, I don't like unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think enough emotion is already portrayed through voting and other user feedback (good and bad). Seeing how worked up people get from just that, I would have to say I would not like this feature.

Comment: there are 2 different satisfactions: visitors satisfaction, and questioner's satisfaction: The ready-nnes of the questioner to change the (unique) answer to an other one.

Answer (score 0):

> but this solution does not satisfy me entirely, cause needs some code changes

Well, of course. You don't want to change the language/culture defaults for Windows and you don't want to change the language/culture defaults for your app - yet you want it to change for *a portion of your app*. That's a very specific need, and requires custom support from the application itself.

There are lots of questions like this, asking for something difficult in the hope that someone else has already done the work, written the code, and perhaps even squirreled it away somewhere in anticipation of just such a question. Sometimes, they get lucky... But otherwise, the best answer to "I want my app to do something unusual" is going to be, "Here's how you'd write some code to make that unusual thing happen".

And that's just fine. Really, it's not too much to expect that programmers asking questions on a programming site should be able to *write computer programs*. Answers that *do* go the extra mile to provide tested, working library-ready code will already tend to get up-voted and accepted over those that don't, so I don't see why adding a way to further snub otherwise helpful answers is necessary.

Comment: *"You don't want to change the language/culture defaults for Windows"* - I would be happy *if this where sufficient*, but this is **NOT**.

Comment: Uh, reading the comments it appears that you just need the MUI version of Windows. Assuming you have access to MSDN, that shouldn't be a problem. But really, that's beside the point - from the sound of it, you don't want to change the UI in Windows anyway, so you're gonna end up adding culture selection to your program as an option somewhere, just like Visual Studio and countless other Windows programs have done in the past. Sucks, but... Making sad faces at the people telling you this doesn't change anything.